# Why d3d effect framework is deprecated?

Tags: directx-9

Per this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/specifying-compiler-targets, it seems the effect framework start from d3d10 is marked as legacy , what is the equivalent in d3d12 (if any) ? many thanks!!!

Comment: The D3D effect framework is deprecated because MS says so. It's a warning that no future development will occur, and that it may disappear in the future (although they don't typically totally remove things). Did you follow the footnote 5 link on the page that you linked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fx_*` profiles are deprecated in the `FXC` compiler and the `D3DCompiler_47.dll` that's available for redistribution and included with the Windows 10 OS. They still work, although `fx_5_0` is missing support for a few newer features from the latest Shader Model 5.0.

The runtime component is the Effects for Direct3D 11. The latest version is on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/FX11), but is provided very much in an "as is" state. It's more or less unchanged for a few years so I marked the repo as 'archive'.

There is no Effects (FX) port for Direct3D 12, and the new Shader Model 6 [DXIL](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXShaderCompiler/) compiler has no support for `fx_*` profiles.

See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/effects-for-direct3d-11-update/)

Now as to **why** is a much longer story, but in the end most engines have their own materials/effects system, so it never got much use for DX10 or DX11.

> If you are looking for a basic material/effects system to learn Direct3D then take a look at *DirectX Tool Kit* for [DX11](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) or [DX12](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/Getting-Started).